# Свойство background

Tags: html, css3

Есть `div`. У него на фоне изображение с фильтром `blur`. Как сделать, чтобы внутри него у содержимого не было этого фильтра?

```
<div class="wrapp">
    <div class="child">
        Привет
    </div> 
</div>

.wrapp {
    width:57%;
    height:450px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:url(http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/7/8/4/3615487.jpg) no-repeat;
    -webkit-filter: blur(7px);
}
.child {
    font-size:25pt;
    color:white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/agbrzmjy/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, что внутри этого `div` вы сможете что-нибудь сделать. Предлагаю следующее решение:

```css
.wrapp {
    width:57%;
    height:450px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:url(http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/7/8/4/3615487.jpg) no-repeat;
    -webkit-filter: blur(7px);
    z-index:-1px;
}
.child {
    position:absolute;
    font-size:25pt;
    color:white;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp"></div>
<span class="child">Привет</span>
```